# Where/How does socat insert packet boundaries?

Tags: macos, socat

I am using `socat` to forward incoming serial traffic to a local UDP port (on macOS):

```
socat OPEN:/dev/cu.usbmodem13203 UDP:localhost:12345
```

I consider a serial device being a streaming interface while UDP is packet-based so there exists no definitive *right* answer where or how to introduce packet boundaries. In my test, every single byte is forwarded as its own UDP packet. For example, when sending the string "XYZ", my test server outputs:

```
Datagram: X
Datagram: Y
Datagram: Z
```

Why is the byte sequence split into several packets at all and what is the mechanism behind it? Is there any way to control that behaviour?

Comment: I suspect (a) that the answer is "whenever the `read()` on the serial port returns, combined with (b) socat is reading the serial device character-by-character (so that bytes are sent when they arrive, rather than waiting to accumulate some buffer before sending)...but I haven't investigated [the source code](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) so I am just guessing.

Comment: Indeed, when the kernel informs Socat that data is available it immediately reads and transfers it. You cannot influence Socat to buffer data or so.
However, when your serial device transfers text (vs.binary data), you may switch it to canonical mode where it provides lines instead of single characters. See documentation of termios, and Socat option icanon.

Comment: I will look into the the icanon socat option. Maybe, I can get away with a base64 encoding then.

Comment: I think, this just gets too complicated: When I want to include base64 encode/decode in the bidirectional communication path, I can not use ordinary (one-directional) pipes so I need to write custom code anyways. So I can also write that code to handle the serial and the UDP socket myself. I'll close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, `socat` always reads and forwards data as soon as it is available on the file descriptor and this behaviour is not meant to be configurable.

So, this is dependent on the kernel and the type of (device) file or underlying driver and not controlled by `socat` itself.